# How to fix the sub-pixel error the way Firefox does?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

If you open this page https://bug63336.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=114574 and try resizing your browser window you should see lines across the black box in any browser other than Firefox. That is due to the sub-pixel error and browsers handle it in different ways. Firefox rounds sub-pixels in such a way that you should see no lines across that black box, but other browsers, namely Opera, Safari, IE, and Chrome, do not fix the sub-pixel problem. So, I would like to learn ways (JavaScript ways, for instance) I could round sub-pixels to fix the sub-pixel error, as Firefox does.

**EDIT:**

Here's one more example that produces this problem in all browsers other than Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/4aMsx/2/

Comment: Yeah, IE8 seems ok, but IE7 does produce the error though.

Answer (score 3):

You can't fix it the way Fx does it, but you can try from the other side.

Why are thee gaps there? Because of the rounding errors. So, we must ensure that there'd be no rounding errors. How'd be do that? At first, we'd *divide* all the space we have and then *multiply* the inner element, so we'd get the situation where the rounding error occurs on the parent and all the children in this context would be ok.

There is a fixed example from the bugzilla: http://jsfiddle.net/2tmjw/

I've added a wrapper with the following styles:

```
#wrapper4wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 8%;
    height: 8%;
}
```

And changed the original wrapper to be

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1000%;
    height: 1000%;
}
```

You can see it in action while resizing the window or the fiddle frame. You can notice that the width of the wrapper is changing by steps: it's where all the rounding errors go.

If you wish to still center a page, you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2tmjw/1/ — but with absolute positioning it's somewhat hard to position it ideally in center. But when it's not absolute positioned and you need to position it horizontally, you can use `display: inline-block` with `text-align: center` or `display: block` with `margin: auto`.

Also, the ratio of the parent's shrinking and the children's expand must be chosen from what parts you want to divide the children. The more precise you want them to be, the less width would the parent have, but the steps would grow too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if this will help. But its worth a try. have a look at this web site. [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/). They use CSS as well as javascript to target browsers for specific problems.

Comment: CSS doesn't help in the situation when, for example, one container that is 300px in width has 3 100px-wide children which are positioned side by side and that container gets dynamically resized to say 200px width and the children are also supposed to be resized accordingly. In the result, each of the children must have around 66.67 width which produces that same subpixel error.

Comment: Inside the parent div try having the children use percentages instead of pixels. E.g: parent = 300px, child1 =width:33%, child2= width:33% child3 =width:33%;

Comment: That was just an example of the problem and I am looking for an algorithm Firefox uses to fix the problem, so it's not about %, really. But thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dont know how FF fix this problem, but adding CSS style `border: 1px solid black;` into `#wrapper div` CSS style rule workarround this problem in all browsers: Chrome, IE7, Opera, Safari.

```
#wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}
```